# Fetch specific data with JS fecth

Tags: javascript, json

Does someone know how to get specific data when working with JavaScript fetch?
I'm working with: https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/constants/exchangerates/global
and not sure how to just pick one currency. I have a `forEach` loop that shows all, but unsure how to just pick one to show.
To show all I use:

```
${data.rates[rate].name}
${data.rates[rate].rate}
```

When I try to just show one I tried with a few different, but I feel like this makes the most sense:

```
${data.rates[rate].name == dkk}
${data.rates[rate].rate}
```

But it does nothing. Does someone know how to specify when you want to only show one set of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
${data.rates[rate].name == dkk}
```

I'm assuming the ${} syntax here is javascript string interpolation.  What you're saying here is "interpolate the value of the equality between .name and dkk".  So this is probably displaying "true" or "false" for you, I'd assume.

What you want to do first is say

```
let displayName = '';
if (data.rates[rate].name === dkk) {
    displayName = data.rates[rate].name;
}
```

And then interpolate ${displayName}.

If this *isn't* what you intend to do, we'd have to see more code.

Comment: this was almost it, but i didnt know you couldt write "dkk" and had to use the full name of the currency.
i posted another comment with what worked for me if you are curious to see.
i also changed the variable in the square brackets since there were too many "rate" and "rates" and looked confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
let html = '';
for (let rateShort in data.rates) {
    const rateObj = data.rates[rateShort];
    html += `${rateObj.name} ${rateObj.rate}<br>`
}
```

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Examples

Answer (score 0):

```
  fetch('https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/constants/exchangerates/global')
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(data => data.rates.AED)
   .then(console.log)
```

since the fetch syntax returns a Promise, you can use .then to work with the data. in the code above I used .then to just return the AED(which is the rate of United Arab Emirates) object from the data recieved from the fetch. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

OP here, figured it would be nice to comment how this was solved in case someone sees this in the future:

```
rates.forEach(currency=>{
 if(data.rates[currency].name == 'Danish Krone'){ //if currency name == 'something'
 output = output +
 `
 ${data.rates[currency].name}
 ${data.rates[currency].rate}<br>
 `
}                    
})
```

so basically you cant write ".name == dkk" to get the name of the currency. i actually had to write an if statement to check if the name == 'currency name'. also(for this api atleast) i couldt write the short version of the currency(dkk), i had to write the full name in the if statement. after that getting the name and rate of the currency was the same as when you loop through all.
hope this helps someone in the future if you end up here :)